# how to get cell type using jopendocument while reading ods cell?

Tags: java, parsing, spreadsheet, ods, jopendocument

I need to parse .ods document to string values.  So, if any of the cell has date, currency or any other format other than number and text I need to get that data according to the cell type and convert it using String.  I'm doing like that so because I don't want my data to get converted while normally getting the value.  So please help with with fetching the data of the cell with the help of cell type and also help me with getting if cell has any formula.

Note : The code should be written in java using jopendoucment jar methods (which will be helpful while parsing ods file where as famous apache poi cannot parse open document formats, I do have the code for that for parsing .xls and .xlsx format as it is written with famous apache poi jar ) .

Thanks for your reply in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MutableCell.getValue()` to get value of cell and `MutableCell.getValueType()` to get data type to define conversion method.